# Ada: Backspace in Appended Text File

Tags: file, cursor, ada, backspace

I have learned that you can open/close a txt file and write to it multiple times (append). Though, everytime I do it begins on a new line. Is there anyway I can get back to exactly where the cursor left off?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use streams and stream attribute `'Write` of type `String`. The attribute denotes a procedure that will output the bare data of a string object.

```
with Ada.Streams.Stream_IO;

procedure Write_Appending is

   use Ada.Streams.Stream_IO;

   F : File_Type;

   procedure Write_Hello is
   begin
      String'Write (Stream (F), "Hello, ");
   end Write_Hello;

   procedure Write_World is
   begin
      String'Write (Stream (F), "World");
   end Write_World;

begin
   Create (F, Name => "Hello.txt");
   Write_Hello;
   Write_World;
   Close (F);

   -- forgot "!", append it at the end of the file.
   Open (F, Mode => Append_File, Name => "Hello.txt");
   Character'Write (Stream (F), '!');
   Close (F);
end Write_Appending;
```

## Resulting file

```
$ cat Hello.txt 
Hello, World!$
```

Note how the last line of the file does not end with a line terminator. For writing to `Current_Output`, consider `Ada.Text_IO.Text_Streams` ([LRM A.12.2](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-12-2.html)).

Comment: Sweet! Now I have the opposite problem though, how do I perform a Carriage Return instead of continuously writing to one line? XD

Comment: `Character'Write` will do it. CR has a fixed ordinal position (`'Pos`) in type `Character`, so using `'Value` with that position is one way of adding CR to output. A more traditional name is `ASCII.CR` from obsolescent package `ASCII`.

Comment: I thought that too.. but heres my code:                                                  write("luck");
 Open(F, Append_File, "Hello.txt");
 Character'Write(Stream(F), ASCII.CR);
 Close(F);                                                                                                nothing happens in the text file except luck being printed on one line when ran multiple times, I may be doing something wrong

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Use another I/O package than `Ada.Text_IO`.  One option could be to use the generic package `Ada.Direct_IO` instantiated with the appropriate character type.